# How to calculate the concentration of reagents and products from Kc?

Tags: equilibrium, concentration

> In the synthesis of ammonia at equilibrium constant is $K_c = 1.2$ according to the reaction:
>   $$\ce{N2 (g) + 3H2 (g) <=> 2NH3 (g)}$$
>   If an equilibrium is proposed based on initial concentrations of $[\ce{H2}] = \pu{ 0.76 M}$, $[\ce{N2}] = \pu{ 0.60 M}]$, $[\ce{NH3}] = \pu{ 0.48 M}$, with $x = 0.014$ as the change in the concentration of $\ce{N2}$, what are the equilibrium concentrations?

Comment: We'll guide you to solve such a problem but not just do it for you. // If the initial concentration of $\ce{N2}$ is 0.60 M, and there is a change of 0.014, what is the final concentration of $\ce{N2}$?

Comment: The final concentration of N2 could be 0.60M-0.014M=0.586

Comment: If that is correct what should I do next?

Comment: What else could he final concentration of $\ce{N2}$ be?

Comment: To me it isn't clear if the change is positive or negative. It seems the problem statement is deliberately ambiguous.

Comment: Independently if the change is positive or negative, because it is not clear for me too, could I use the final concentration of N2 and initial concentration of the other elements to calculate something? How would be the process of calculating the concentration of the other elements?

Comment: You're on the right idea! Let's start with the final concentration of $\ce{N2}$ being 0.586. What must the concentrations of $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{NH3}$  be? // Then consider the positive change. What must the concentrations of $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{NH3}$  be?

Comment: Mmm I am not understanding it at all. The negative change is N2=0.586M and the positive change is N2=0.614. Then with these changes, does kc=1.2 change too?

Comment: How does the change of N2 affect the other elements?

Comment: No $K_c$ must be a constant (for the given temperature...). // Back to the concentrations for a moment. If there is less nitrogen when the equilibrium is established, where did it go? // LOL - Scotty on the Starship Enterprise didn't just beam the nitrogen out!

Comment: **HINT** the course is chemistry, not Transwarp Wormhole Fluid Dynamics. ;-)

Comment: If there is less nitrogen in the equilibruim, is it now represented in an increase of NH3?

Comment: Yes, if the nitrogen decreases then the ammonia increases. What else must decrease? Use the chemical equation!!

Comment: One molecule of nitrogen reacts with 3 molecules of hydrogen and the reaction yields two molecules of ammonia. // A mole is just a big counting unit like a dozen or a million. So one mole of nitrogen reacts with 3 moles of hydrogen and the reaction yields two moles of ammonia. // So how do all the concentrations change?

Comment: Well for example if we have 0.586 M and the volume is despicable we have 0.586 moles of N2 too. Then if we have one mole of N2 for every three moles of H2 we will have to multiply 0.586 * 3 to get the moles of H2. Then the same with NH2. And then the concentrations are going to be the same as the moles we found because the volume is despicable. Is this correct?

Comment: The hydrogen change is not 0.586 * 3.

Answer (score 1):

The given chemical reaction is:

$$\ce{N2(g) + 3H2(g) <=> 2NH3(g)}$$

So:

- One molecule of nitrogen reacts with 3 molecules of hydrogen and the reaction yields two molecules of ammonia.
- A mole is just a big counting unit like a dozen or a million. So one mole of nitrogen reacts with 3 moles of hydrogen and the reaction yields two moles of ammonia.

The problem states "with x = 0.014 as the change in the concentration of $\ce{N2}$". It isn't clear if the change is positive or negative. It seems the problem statement is deliberately ambiguous.

So using the stoichiometry from the chemical reaction, if nitrogen changes by $-x$, then hydrogen changes by $-3x$, and the nitrogen changes by $+2x$. Conversely if nitrogen changes by $+x$, then hydrogen changes by $+3x$, and the nitrogen changes by $-2x$.

Now for the equilibrium:

$$K_\mathrm{c} = 1.2 = \dfrac{\ce{[NH3]^2}}{\ce{[N2][H2]^3}}$$

So we can calculate $K_\mathrm{c}$ for the various compositions of the gases and see if any is equal to 1.2.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
& \pu{\ce{[N2]}} & \pu{\ce{[H2]}} & \pu{\ce{[NH3]}} & \pu{calc}\ K_\mathrm{c} \\ \hline
\pu{initial} & 0.600 & 0.760 & 0.48 & 0.875\\ \hline
\pu{\Delta \ce{N2 = +0.014}} & 0.614 & 0.802  & 0.452 & 0.645\\ \hline
\pu{\Delta \ce{N2 = -0.014}} & 0.586 & 0.718 & 0.508 & 1.19 \\ \hline
\end{array}

So the composition of the gases must be equal to the last line in the table.

Comment: Interestingly the question poses a reaction in the gas phase, but then uses molarity. I don't think it is asked very well.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン - I agree. I also don't like problem specifying 2 digit concentrations when to follow the change need three digits are needed. So 0.60 molar for $\ce{N2}$ magically must turn into 0.600 molar.